# Object.assign is modifying original array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to modify a property value of a specific index in my state this property is the `post_comments` But my problem is the state is being modified even though i am only modifying the copy of it.. The code works how i want it to be but i'm modifying the state so it's probably bad how do i fix this?

```
socket.on('statusComment', (data) => {
    const mutator =  Object.assign([], this.state.getStatus);
    const index =  mutator.findIndex(i => i._id === data._id);
    mutator[index].post_comments = data.post_comments; // Replace old post_comments with data.post_comments 
    console.log(mutator) // Got the post_comments 
    console.log(this.state.getStatus) // Also modified 

    // Commented out setState
    // this.setState({
    //     getStatus: mutator
    // })
});
```

---

Here is a sample `data` detected by socket

```
const data = {
  post_id: "5b0689f03fb2fd1404f1854d",
  post_comments: [{text: 'what'}]
}
```

This is what my state looks like

```
   const data_arr = [
      {
        "post_img": [],
        "post_date": "2018-05-24T09:46:24.948Z",
        "post_comments": [
          {
            "comment_posted": "2018-05-24T09:46:31.015Z",
            "_id": "5b0689f73fb2fd1404f1854e",
            "comment_from": {
              "photo_url": "png",
              "_id": "5af16d60f3957c11e46500ae",
              "display_name": "Lumpo"
            },
            "comment_text": "kaka2"
          },
          {
            "comment_posted": "2018-05-24T09:47:42.752Z",
            "_id": "5b068a3e2fdd6f141d5ba995",
            "comment_from": {
              "photo_url": "png",
              "_id": "5af16d60f3957c11e46500ae",
              "display_name": "Lumpo"
            },
            "comment_text": "kaka!"
          }
        ],
        "_id": "5b0689f03fb2fd1404f1854d",
        "post_description": "get out\r\n",
        "post_by": {
          "photo_url": "png",
          "_id": "5af16d60f3957c11e46500ae",
          "display_name": "Lumpo"
        },
        "__v": 2
      }
    ]
```

Spread operator is not working logs the same thing with the `Object.assign` method
// console.log(mutator)

```
[
  {
    "post_img": [],
    "_id": "5b0694cc7925c914e4d95dda",
    "post_description": "test",
    "post_by": {
      "_id": "5af16d60f3957c11e46500ae",
      "display_name": "Lumpo",
      "photo_url": "png"
    },
    "post_comments": [
      {
        "_id": "5b0694d67925c914e4d95ddb",
        "comment_from": {
          "photo_url": "png",
          "_id": "5af16d60f3957c11e46500ae",
          "display_name": "Lumpo"
        },
        "comment_text": "This comment should only be in the mutator ",
        "comment_posted": "2018-05-24T10:32:54.937Z"
      }
    ],
    "post_date": "2018-05-24T10:32:44.613Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

// console.log(this.state.getStatus);

```
[
  {
    "post_img": [],
    "_id": "5b0694cc7925c914e4d95dda",
    "post_description": "test",
    "post_by": {
      "_id": "5af16d60f3957c11e46500ae",
      "display_name": "Lumpo",
      "photo_url": "png"
    },
    "post_comments": [
      {
        "_id": "5b0694d67925c914e4d95ddb",
        "comment_from": {
          "photo_url": "png",
          "_id": "5af16d60f3957c11e46500ae",
          "display_name": "Lumpo"
        },
        "comment_text": "This comment should only be in the mutator ",
        "comment_posted": "2018-05-24T10:32:54.937Z"
      }
    ],
    "post_date": "2018-05-24T10:32:44.613Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const mutator =  Object.assign([], this.state.getStatus);
```

its  doing `shallow/reference` copy of array.

So,original array is copied as it is using reference.

Use [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create new  copy of  array and then do JSON.stringify followed by JSON.parse.U need a deep copy.

```
let mutator = [...this.state.getStatus];
mutator = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mutator));
```

Comment: It's doing the same thing the state still gets modified.

Comment: Could u please share the `this.state.getStatus` output

Comment: @markuspaterson please check the updates answer last line

Comment: Check my question i put the output there

Comment: Parsing the mutator works but is this ideal? Why do i need to do it ?

Comment: yes,there is nothing wrong,as you a needed a deep copy.otherwise u have to write your custom deep copy function or use function lib which do this like loadash.

Comment: Using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObject)) is a far more expensive operation and has the disadvantage that every member (and it's sub members) of the state has a new reference (also the items that did not change). This would cause components to re render that don't need to re render.

Comment: Till one not using setState or forceUpdate how its possible to re-render just because of striginiy and parse

Comment: I updated my answer. If you have an array and map it then all items in that array still have same reference except one. If you use componentShouldUpdate to check referential equality of state versus previous state then only one of the child components will actually re render. If state also has other members then components using these  members as state will also needlessly re render.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.assign([], this.state.getStatus)
```

`[]` is an array, <strike>not an object</strike>. This is likely causing a problem.

Edit: See Josh’s comment, it is an object, but also an array. But the behaviour will be different to if it were an object object.

Comment: It's an array _and_ an object.

Comment: Since the array has objects this is will not solve the mutation problem. You need to `someArray.map(item=>(item._id===data._id)?{...item,newProp:data.newProp}:item)`

Answer (score 1):

you can copy your array something like this :

```
 const mutator =  [...this.state.getStatus];
```

Comment: Since the array has objects this is will not solve the mutation problem. You need to `someArray.map(item=>(item._id===data._id)?{...item,newProp:data.newProp}:item)`

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to make a copy of an existing array without copying a reference is the following:

```
const mutator = this.state.getStatus.slice(0);
```

as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Since the array has objects this is will not solve the mutation problem. You need to `someArray.map(item=>(item._id===data._id)?{...item,newProp:data.newProp}:item)`

Answer (score 0):

Your state is an object containing an array of objects.

First you copy state and reset the array `getStatus` with `getStatus` mapped. When the status item is found that needs to change you copy that item but set post_comments with another value (see code below).

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,//copy state
  getStatus: this.state.getStatus.map(//getStatus is a new array
    (item,index)=>
      (item._id===data._id)//if item._id is data._id
        ? {...item,post_comments:data.post_comments}//copy item but reset post_comments
        : item//not the item we are looking for, return item (not changed copy)
  )
})
```

If you need more help the please let me know.

Using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)))` will cause all components to re render even if their part of the state did not change (deep copy versus shallow copy). You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to see if the state actually changed and tell react not to re render components where this did not happen. However; since you are deep copying everything (not only the items that changed) you cannot do this.

Here is an example of a base component that checks if the state passed to it actually changed reference and should re render:

```
import React from 'react';
class OnlyIfChanged extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps.state !== this.props.state;
  }
}
export default OnlyIfChanged;
```

Comment: Works amazingly too but i don't understand it haha

Comment: @markuspaterson the spread syntax({...this.state})  makes a shallow copy of the state and the `,getStatus:this.state.getStatus.map` re assigns the `getStatus` property of the shallow copied state. The `this.state.getStatus.map` [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the `getStatus` array to a new array, if the item with the correct id is found then item is copied using spread `{...item}` and post_comments is re assigned in that copy.

Comment: @markuspaterson Using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObject)) is a far more expensive operation and has the disadvantage that every member of the state has a new reference (also the items that did not change). This would cause components to re render that don't need to re render.

Comment: @markuspaterson Updated my answer with the disadvantages using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify